# Prove an equation has a solution in within specific interval (IVT)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ be **positive** real numbers s.t $b_1+b_2+\dots+b_n=n$.
How can I prove that the equation: $\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot \ln(b_k)\cdot x^{k-1}\cdot b_k^{x^k}  = 0$
has a solution over the interval of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Setting $x = 0$ work.

Comment: Why is that? can you explain in details please?

Comment: Presumably you mean you want to summation to equal $1$ for some $x \in [0,1]$. Setting $x = 0$ gives $0$ for every term since $x^{k-1}$ is in each product. However, the term for $k=1$ is undefined since in this initial term we have the undefined $0^0$, so I am not sure that @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會's suggestion works.

Comment: @DerekLuna My bad.  Thx 4 correction.

Answer (score 3):

Define $\displaystyle f(x) := \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k^{x^k}$. Note that $\displaystyle f(0) = \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k^0 = n$ and $\displaystyle f(1) = \sum_{k = 1}^n b_k = n$. Thus, using Rolle's Theorem, we can conclude that for some $c \in [0,1]$, $f'(c) = 0$. In other words, $\displaystyle f'(x) = \sum_{k =1}^n k \cdot \ln(b_k) \cdot x^{k-1} \cdot b_k^{x^k} = 0$ has a solution in $[0,1]$.